# C++ checking floats

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, floating-point

Right, I have an array for floats which stores only 1s and 0s. I'm trying to just do a simply test/check that the current slot in the array is 1 it will print out a little message to say it is 1, otherwise, it is 0. Heres my code:

```
if(myArray[i] == 1)
{
    cout << "this is 1 !!!!!" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "this is 0 ";
}
```

but this just keeps entering the "else" section. i.e. only printing "this is 0". Whats wrong with it (or whats wrong with me?? :P)??

Comment: Too little information here.  we need to see what is getting into the array. EDIT: Yes, this is a bad design.  The top answers right now go off on that a bit.  But to answer specifically why this particular implementation isnt working, we need more code.

Comment: don't use `float` if you're not absolutely sure you need them and understand their shortcomings.

Comment: Any time you use == to compare floating point numbers, you are almost certainly doing something wrong

Comment: Curious why you are using floats if you only need to store 1 and 0's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great link: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

After reading that you'll realise that the floating-point representation of 1 isn't quite the integer value 1. It's close, but not quite, and that's why your condition will always be false.

Why would you use `float`s to store boolean data? Use an array of `bool`s or a bitvector.

EDIT: I can't actually think of any situation where (or why) you'd compare `float`s to a literal, anyone know any?

Answer (score 3):

When operating with floating point numbers you should program a little more defensive:

```
if (myArray[i] == 1) {
  cout << "this is 1\n";
} else if (myArray[i] == 0) {
  cout << "this is 0\n";
} else {
  cout << "this is something else, in particular " << myArray[i] << "\n";
}
```

This should give you an insight about what happens.

By the way, if you only ever store the values `1.0f` and `0.0f` in the array, it is perfectly ok to use the `==` operator to compare floats. You just have to be sure that what you *think* is `1.0` is really really really `1.0`.

Comment: +1. And even if it *prints* as `1.00000`, it still might not really really really be `1.0`.

Comment: Exactly, and if you experience this case, you can still print `1000.0 * (myArray[i] - printedValue)` to see the difference through a magnifying glass.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use floats to store a `1` or a `0`.  There is no reason to use a `float` to store  small integers.

Second, you need to read into [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Numbers.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)  Though it will often work, you should compare floating point values by taking the absolute value of the difference between them and comparing *that* with some small sigma (where sigma is a value that makes sense in your application within the valid range of precision).

If `abs( x - y ) < sigma` you can consider them equal.

Comment: About the "comparing to a small sigma", this is very "naive" (no offense intended) and as always the answer is more complicated. You are referring to the absolute error there which is fine for certain category of numbers. If your numbers are small then this might not work anymore. Check out any numerical analysis text or something like http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Comment: @Alexandre Abreu: Correct, which is why I also said *where sigma is a value that makes sense in your application within the valid range of precision*.  I could have added *that sigma may not exist*, but for the vast majority of cases a sigma is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you arrived at the values in your array (i.e. the result of computations), it's highly unlikely that you'll get an exact 0 or 1 as a floating point result.  Checking if a float == 1 exactly will almost certainly be false in that case.

On the other hand, in IEEE floating point, an exact 0 is stored as 0x00000000.  If it's not the result of a computation, sticking a 0 in your array can be useful as a flag instead of storing a separate array.

Answer (score 0):

There could be very good reason that the value in your floating point array is off by very slight fraction to be equal to 1.

Though this is not a clean solution, this should be reason enough to use either enum or a bool array.

```
if(myArray[i] > 0.9f && myArray[i] < 1.00001f)
...
...
```

Comment: 0.9 is very far from 1.0, compared to 1.00001.

Comment: Why are you posting [multiple answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988558/c-checking-floats/7988574#7988574)? If you know of multiple solutions to the problem add them to the same answer. You can always edit an answer after you've submitted it.

Comment: @RolandIllig: It was an example only to show a range might be solution, the exact figure would depend on the dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered something about this 
[here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/10953/). You can't do a "==" to compare float and int.

In your case, maybe the float 1 is actually 0.9999999 which will be truncated to 0, which is the output of your program is already correct.

Answer (score -1):

Either cast the array element to an `int`:

```
if ((int)myArray[i] == 1)
```

Or cast the `1` to a `float`:

```
if (myArray[i] == 1.0f)
```